# Use of Qtimer before event loop started

Tags: qt5, slot, qtimer

I have created a simple, single thread, app in Qt6.  My sole class creates a couple of timers and prints a qDebug message in the timeout slot.  These messages never print.

My class is created before the app.exec() in main, so before the event loop is executed.  I suspect this is related.  If I create QTimers and connect the timeout signal, before the event loop exec is called, are my signals-slots lost once exec is called?  What's the right way to handle this?

Note: This question is about use of QTimer & Eventloop.  Not looking for help with specific code.  (i.e. theory)

Comment: Sorry, but do you really expect anyone will be able to help you without seeing any code.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The question is meant to be theoretical - can I post events before starting the event loop, or are they lost?  I've used enough QTimers that I don't need code help.

Answer (score 0):

After testing I can confirm that events posted before the event loop starts (.exec) are queued.  Similarly, connects created before the event loop starts are also retained - so once the vent loop starts those slots receive the attached signals.